# ScreenManager RecycleView not showing item

Tags: python-3.x, android-recyclerview, kivy, screen, kivymd

The following code runs without any error, can't understand why the RV items are not showing- The screen shows up blank but when I put other items they show up. Could be a simple fix.  I have followed several examples but a similar issue persists.

Any sugestions is welcome. still on a learning path

KV

```
<RecycleViewRow>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: root.text
    Button:
        text: 'Show'
        on_press: app.root.message_box(root.text)

<MainScreen>:

RecycleView:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'RecycleViewRow'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

from pathlib import Path, PurePath

# Music Path
storageLocation = Path.cwd()
if Path('Books').is_dir():
    storageLocation = Path.cwd() / 'Books'
    # Check if file is in SD card
# elif Path.is_mount():
else:
    storageLocation = Path.cwd() / 'Books'
    storageLocation.mkdir()

class RecycleViewRow(BoxLayout):
    text = StringProperty()

class Playlist(Screen):
    pass


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        songs = []
        booksdir = [f for f in storageLocation.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]

        if Path('Books').is_dir():
            for filename in storageLocation.glob('**/*.wav'):
                songs.append(filename)
        # self.data = [{'text': str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in booksdir]

        self.data = [{'text': "Button " + str(x), 'id': str(x)} for x in range(100)]



class Main(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='MainScreen'))
      # sm.add_widget(Playlist(name='Playlist'))
        return sm


Main().run()
```

Comment: Glancing at the code I noticed that `self.data` is in the `MainScreen` class. You will want to have that point to your `RecycleView`, which you can achieve by passing `self.children[0].data` instead of just `self`

Comment: Also the indentation of the `RecycleView` in the kv file is incorrect. I am not sure if this is just a SO issue but it should be within `MainScreen`.

Comment: and abrakadabra self.root.data.  ****** it works

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)